# No overfitting by increasing the number of epochs

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning

I use a feed foreward neural network with one hidden layer for my thesis. Threby I have 600 training data and 104 input and output values. There I want to show now the properties of the neural network and also want to show the overfitting when I increase the number of epochs.
To do so, I first wanted to find the optimum for learning rate and number of hidden nodes, where I got the following results:
[image]

[image]

Based on that I decided to choose a learning rate of 0.0125 and 250 hidden nodes. But by using this set of parameters, I still have no overfitting when I increase the number of epochs, which can be seen here:

[image]

In this plot I showed in blue my old set of parameters and in theory I wanted to show how it improve when I use the best set of parameters, but it's just varying a bit. I also tested it until epoch 1000 but the accuracy with this value was still 0.830.

Does someone has an idea why this happen?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear from the post why exactly would you want your network to overfit. I suspect from the wording that you're trying to demonstrate the universal approximation theorem - in that case the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_approximation_theorem) page may contain the key insight

> The theorem thus states that simple neural networks *can* represent a wide variety of interesting functions when given appropriate parameters; however, it does not touch upon the algorithmic *learnability* of those parameters.

In other words, you are guaranteed that there exists a large enough network of yours and a specific choice of parameters which would (over)fit your dataset, but you are not guaranteed to observe this overfitting behavior with whatever optimization scheme you actually employ.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your informations. Yes, I wanted to demonstrate the theorem, but with my parameters I couldn't realize it.